# Different symlink for different user on Windows

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I have an app which saves its data on `C:\ProgramData`. That means for all users, it uses the same data. I want to achieve a way, so that different users can have their own separate data space. I have used symlink (folder junction) to create it to `%userprofile%\Documents\AppFolder`, and the method works fine on my user profile, but when tried with different user the app doesn't run; as it tries to access `C:\User\User1\Documents\AppFolder`, which User2 doesn't have access. Any possible workaround, so the different users can link to different symlinks?

Comment: What application is this? Maybe you can change this in the app's settings?

Comment: I tried. The app writes its settings on a ini file inside the program directory. If the ini file can be symlinked, I think the problem can be solved too. (But have to be two different symlink for two user).

Its a private company app, and the developer of this app are unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subst` command to map a drive letter to your user directory. Drive letters created by `subst` are per-user, so you can create the same mapping as each user and then create a symlink to that drive letter. Or just point the program to the mapped drive via its settings.

An example:

```
subst v: %userprofile%
mklink /d c:\ProgramData\AppFolder v:\Documents\AppForder
```

A downside of this solution is that mapped drive letters are not persistent, so you have to recreate them every time a user logs in (for example, by putting a shortcut to the `subst` command into `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. Or you can make a batch file which will run `subst` and then your program.

An alternative solution is to run your program in a sandbox (e.g. [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/)).This won't work if the program tries to do something low-level (e.g. installing drivers or services). Also you'll have to restore files created by the program from sandbox after each run in you need to use them elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and the subst method seems promising, but I'm a little confused. As I want to keep the login and other data for two users separate, should I map to different drives for different users? V for User1, W for User2? Or same? If same, wouldn't it replace the existing data for the other user?

Comment: Both users will have the same drive letter, but it will point to different directories. The symlink will not change.